# python trim tab from file

Tags: python-3.x, readfile

I am importing a tab separated file.

```
import csv
with open(logfile) as f:
    csvlines = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in csvlines:
        print(row)
 prints [' mike            john              steve']
```

Is there a way to have it print

```
 make|steve|john
```

I tried using `csv.DictReader` but since it's not a true csv file is mucks up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
import csv
logfile = "t.txt"

with open(logfile,"w") as f:
    f.write('mike\tjohn\tsteve\n')
    f.write('mike           john           steve\n')  # no tabs, just spaces

with open(logfile) as f:
    csvlines = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for row in csvlines:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['mike', 'john', 'steve']
['mike           john           steve']
```

You probably have a space seperated file before you .... hence all are matched into one column.

---

You can parse a space separated file by:

```
with open(logfile) as f:
    csvlines = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in csvlines:
        print(row)
```

Wich gives you:

```
['mike\tjohn\tsteve']        # no spaces, all in one column
['mike', 'john', 'steve']    # multiple consecutive spaces = 1 column-divider
```

Comment: yeah i am getting a bunch of empty values in the list `['','','','john','steve']`